# v2 and v3 general model characters per day limit issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are getting the below mentioned error for the translate.googleapis.com.
WE have not exceeded the limit and used less than the previous day. Does any one know the issue here

```
"message": "8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota Error: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED Quota exceeded for quota metric 'v2 and v3 general model characters' and limit 'v2 and v3 general model characters per day' of service 'translate.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:100xxx'."
```

Answer (score 2):

As John suggested, you should open a case with GCP support for these kind of issues. You can do so by following these steps [1].

Have a nice day!

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases

Answer (score 1):

If you are convinced that you have not exceeded the quota, the only place you can get help is Google Cloud Support. The message is very clear, Google Cloud has determined that you have exceeded your quota.

Ask Google Cloud to investigate.

Stackoverflow cannot solve this for you. This is a vendor support problem.